# When click on user open a modal with full information of the user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, material-ui

**I am passing the user through to the modal ViewUser to show it data but it always show the same user when clicking in different user, I need to know how can I specify the user who I need to show their data, I send it in ViewUser component as user **

```js
const UserList = () => {
    const [confirmDel, setConfirmDel] = useState(false);
    const [showData, setShowData] = useState(false);
    const usersList = useAppSelector((state) => state.users);

    const handleShowDataOpen = () => {
        setShowData(true);
    };

    const handleShowDataClose = () => {
        setShowData(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.main_container}>
                <h1>Users List</h1>
                {usersList.length === 0 ? (
                    <span className={styles.empty_container}>
                        No current registered users
                    </span>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                            <Table aria-label="simple table" size="small">
                                <TableHead>
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell>Username</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>First Name</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Age</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Action</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
                                        {usersList.map((user) => (
                                            <TableRow key={user.username}>
                                                <TableCell>
                                                    <Button variant="text" onClick={handleShowDataOpen}>
                                                        {user.username}
                                                    </Button>
                                                    <ViewUser showData={showData} user={user} handleShowDataClose={handleShowDataClose} />
                                                </TableCell>
                                                <TableCell>{user.firstName}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell>{user.age}</TableCell>
                                                
                                                                                                </TableRow>
                                    ))}
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        </TableContainer>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean state for `showData` is being set to true, which means that the `ViewUser` component is being shown for *every* user at the same time.

Instead, you could store the index of the single user which you want to show at a single time.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { data } from "./data";

const UserList = () => {
  const [showData, setShowData] = useState(null);
  const usersList = data;

  const handleShowDataOpen = (index) => {
    setShowData(index);
  };

  const handleShowDataClose = () => {
    setShowData(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Users List</h1>
        {usersList.length === 0 ? (
          <span>No current registered users</span>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div>
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {usersList.map((user, index) => (
                    <tr key={user.id}>
                      <td>
                        <button
                          variant="text"
                          onClick={() => handleShowDataOpen(index)}
                        >
                          {user.firstName} {user.lastName}
                        </button>
                        <ViewUser
                          showUser={showData === index}
                          user={user}
                          handleShowDataClose={handleShowDataClose}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                      <td>{user.age}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserList;

const ViewUser = ({ user, showUser, handleShowDataClose }) => {
  return showUser ? (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
        padding: 20
      }}
    >
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(user)}</pre>
      <button onClick={handleShowDataClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

[image: Edit optimistic-snowflake-skmk9u]

---

Alternatively, create a separate `User` component, and keep the `open` state inside it instead of in `UserList`.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { data } from "./data";

const UserList = () => {
  const usersList = data;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Users List</h1>
        {usersList.length === 0 ? (
          <span>No current registered users</span>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div>
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {usersList.map((user) => (
                    <User user={user} />
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserList;

const User = ({ user }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <tr key={user.id}>
      <td>
        <button variant="text" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
          {user.firstName} {user.lastName}
        </button>
        <ViewUser
          showUser={isOpen}
          user={user}
          handleShowDataClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        />
      </td>
      <td>{user.firstName}</td>
      <td>{user.age}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const ViewUser = ({ user, showUser, handleShowDataClose }) => {
  return showUser ? (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
        padding: 20
      }}
    >
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(user)}</pre>
      <button onClick={handleShowDataClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

[image: Edit blissful-keller-3mjpde]